# How to set name value of dynamic adding input ? javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page for applying. In this web page, rows are dynamic add after addp button clicked.I can add new row successfully with addPf() method. And these input name attribute should be enName0, enName1, enName2....., but it works fail with name="enName"+aDWI.

Here is my html code:

```
<div>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="button" id="addP" onclick="addPf()" value="addPeople">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   new row added in here;
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>

 var aDWI=0;
 function addPf()
 {
    newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName"+aDWI></td></tr>';
    $(newrow).insertAfter($('#staTable tr:eq('+aDWI+')'));
     aDWI = aDWI + 1;
  }
</script>
```

name="enName"+aDWI is not right.I have no idea about this, who can help me ?

Comment: `newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName"' + aDWI + '></td></tr>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName"+aDWI></td></tr>';
```

to

```
newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName'+aDWI+'"></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update it with

```
<script>

 var aDWI=0;
 function addPf()
 {
    newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName'+aDWI+'"></td></tr>';
   $(newrow).insertAfter($('#staTable tr:eq('+aDWI+')'));
   aDWI = aDWI + 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. The double quote need to be around the value: `name="enName'+aDWI+'"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you need to concatenate the variable in the string correctly, using the `'` character.

Also note that you should really be using unobtrusive event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. In addition, you can simplify the logic by using jQuery's `append()`, like this:

```js
var aDWI = 0;

$('#addP').click(function() {
  newrow = '<tr><td><input style="width:98%" name="enName' + aDWI + '" value="' + aDWI + '"></td></tr>';
  $('#staTable').append(newrow);
  aDWI = aDWI + 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="staTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="addP" value="addPeople">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        new row added in here;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```